# Quiero guardar el registro de errores php en la carpeta del script

Tags: php, linux, ec2

Estoy trabajando con una instancia Linux 2 de Amazon y quiero que se creen los error_log de php en la carpeta donde corre el script que produce el error. ¿Como tengo que hacer esto?. Gracias!

Comment: Si tienes acceso a php.ini, puedes definirlo así:

`error_log = /ruta/donde/guardar/errores`

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, el tema es que la ruta quiero que sea la del script que produce el error, no una ruta fija. Gracias!